# Smallest field of rationality of a subspace of a linear space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

The following definitions and proposition are due to Bourbaki's Algebra Ch. II.

Let $K$ be an extension of a field $k$.

**Definition 1**
Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$.
Let $V_0$ be a $k$-subspace of $V$.
Suppose the canonical homomorphism $V_0\otimes_k K \rightarrow V$ is an isomorphism.
Then $V_0$ is called a $k$-structure of $V$.

**Definition 2**
Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$.
Let $V_0$ be a $k$-structure of $V$.
Let $W$ be a $K$-subspace of $V$.
If there exists a $k$-subspace $W_0$ of $V_0$ such that $W = W_0K$, then we say $W$ is rational over $k$.

**Example**
Let $K[X_1,\dots, X_n]$ be the polynomial ring over $K$.
Then $k[X_1,\dots, X_n]$ is a $k$-structure of $K[X_1,\dots, X_n]$.
Let $I$ be an ideal of $K[X_1,\dots,X_n]$.
Suppose $I$ is generated by polynomials of $k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$.
Then $I$ is rational over $k$.

Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$.
Let $V_0$ be a $k$-structure of $V$.
Let $L$ be a subfield of $K$ such that $k \subset L \subset K$.
Clearly $V_0L$ is a $L$-structure of $V$.

**Proposition**
Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$.
Let $V_0$ be a $k$-structure of $V$.
Let $W$ be a $K$-subspace of $V$.
Let $\mathfrak{F} = \{$subfield $L | k\subset L \subset K\}$.
Let $\mathfrak{R} = \{L \in \mathfrak{F}| W$ is rational over $L\}$.
Then $\mathfrak{R}$ has a least element.

**My question**
Bourbaki proves the above proposition using results on rationality of a linear map.
Is there a more direct proof?

**EDIT**
Let $(v_i)_{i\in I}$ be a basis of $V_0$ over $k$.
By the assumption, this is also a basis of $V$ over $K$.
Since $V/W$ is generated by the set $\{v_i$ mod $W| i \in I\}$ over $K$, there exists a subset $J \subset I$ such that $(v_j$ mod $W)_{j\in J}$ is a basis of $V/W$ over $K$.
For each $i \in I - J$,

$v_i \equiv \sum_{j\in J} \alpha_{ij} v_j$ mod $W$, where $\alpha_{ij} \in K$

Then we need to prove that $k(\{\alpha_{i,j}| i \in I - J, j \in J\})$ is the desired subfield.

**Motivation**
The above proposition is important in arithmetic theory of algebraic varieties as the above example shows.

**[Related link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110939/origin-of-the-theorem-on-the-existence-of-the-smallest-field-of-definition-of-an)**

Comment: Is there something unclear in the answer for MO ?

Comment: @QiL xbvn in the above link just stated that, in our notation, $k(\{\alpha_{i,j}| i \in I - J, j \in J\})$ is the desired subfield. I would like to know its proof.